# subfloats vspace between its subcaption

Tags: spacing, subfloats

How can I decrease the vspace between a subfloat and its caption? I have already tried this:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[small,sc,bf,nooneline,skip=5pt]{caption} % Nicer formatting of figure captions.
\usepackage{subfig,float}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{captionskip=3pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%%----start of first subfigure----
\subfloat[yyy]{
\label{subfig:a} %% label for first subfigure
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{fig1.eps}}\\[5pt]
%%----start of 2nd subfigure----
\subfloat[xxx]{
\label{subfig:b} %% label for third subfigure
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{fig2.eps}}
\caption{Cap}
\label{fig} %% label for entire figure
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

Your have loaded the package `caption` incorrectly.

`small`, `sc`, `bf`, `nooneline` are *not* package options. You can use the font setting 
`small`, `sc`, `bf` with the package options `font`,`labelfont` and `textfont`.

An example:

```
\usepacakge[labelfont={bf,sc},texfont=small]{caption}
```

The option `nooneline` is no longer supported. Instead, use `singlelinecheck=off`. The documentation of `caption` listed such changes in the appendix.

The documentation can be found on your computer with

```
texdoc caption
```

or CTAN:
[caption on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/)

In relation to you minimal example:

```
\documentclass[demo]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig,float}
\usepackage[skip=5pt,font={bf,sc,small},singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{captionskip=50pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%%----start of first subfigure----
\subfloat[yyy]{
\label{subfig:a} %% label for first subfigure
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{fig1.eps}}\\[5pt]
%%----start of 2nd subfigure----
\subfloat[xxx]{
\label{subfig:b} %% label for third subfigure
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{fig2.eps}}
\caption{Cap}
\label{fig} %% label for entire figure
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. You are the native speaker ;-)

Comment: No problem. Don't want to be too forward with edits.

Comment: @Werner: In this way I improve my English. That's a nice gimmick of TeX.sx. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But the vertical space is still there, isn't it? That gap is exactly what I would like to remove.

Comment: @sil_leu: WHich gap? You can use the option `captionskip=50pt` (see exeample)?